# How to access the XML which comes out of Dataweave

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component, dataweave

I try to access the elements under xml which is comes out of DataWeave. It gives returns me null values.

DataWeave Script is

```
%dw 1.0
%namespace ns0 urn:abc:dbc:Components
%output text/xml
---
ItemFee:{
    product_id:flowVars."Dept_id",
    TotalFees: sum payload.ns0#ItemResponse.ns0#Fees.*ns0#Fee.ns0#Fee
}
```

Immediate after to this dataweave i have logger node with below message.

```
#[message.payload.ItemFee.TotalFees]
```

I am getting error saying

```
Execution of the expression "message.payload.ItemFee.TotalFees" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler
```

I like to say one more point here. When i give below text in the logger immediate after 'Transform Message'. The message printed in the console without issue. But i could not access the elements in the xml message.`#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That MEL syntax only works with Java objects. As the ouput is XML, you will have to use the `xpath3` MEL function:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath#the-xpath3-function

Something like:

```
#[xpath3('//ItemFee/TotalFees').text]
```

Comment: When i give `#[xpath3('//ItemFee/TotalFees').text]` in my logger, it shows that it got Null message in the console.
`INFO  2015-12-18 14:24:02,696 [[ebay_dec15th2015].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: null`
Though i am setting 'text/xml' format in dataweaver. When it comes out of 'Transform Message' component it looks like object.

Comment: I like to say one more point here. When i give below text in the logger immediate after 'Transform Message'. The message printed in the console without issue. But i could not access the elements in the xml message.`#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]`

Comment: Ryan is there a way to print in console while transformation like we do in XSLT or java?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ryan. Your answer helped me. I have entered below in my logger. Then i am able to fetch the items.

```
#[xpath3('//ItemFee/TotalFees')]
```

Earlier i tried these stuff's i am not sure why it not worked earlier. Might be i have overlooked the issue. :)